# how to represent a constant function, for example, 1

Tags: overleaf, function

\mathbbm{1} is better to be a characteristic function. So how to write the constant function 1?

Comment: This feels a bit opinion based.  Once you decide how you want to represent the constant function, then we can help out.  My preference would be to not define a new notation, and instead use `\mathbbm{1}_{\mathbb{R}}`.

Comment: This is not really a typesetting problem, but a problem on mathematical writing style. I don't think this is on topic for this forum. // That said, I cannot resist remarking that the constant $1$ function is just the characteristic function of the entire domain, so a better question is what you want the constant 2 function to look like.

Answer (score 0):

How about

[image]

In plain-TeX:

```
The function $f(x)=1$, for all $x\in R$, is an example of a constant function on $R$.
\bye
```